# js functions not working when called from a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Javascript, jQuery functions are not working when called from a lightbox. I just want a div to be displayed, when I click on a link. But it doesn't work. When I tried checking by displaying an alert box, on click of the link, that also doesn't work. What could be the possible reason. This problem is only on this page, the same function works in other pages.
I have included all the necessary js files as in other pages.

**EDIT**

The html code in the lightbox:

```
<div id="bottom_eqn_section" class="paddingTop_10">
  <a id="cost_allocation" href="#" class="arrowLink">Change cost allocation</a> 
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <a id="cancel" href="#" class="arrowLink ">Cancel</a>
</div>
<button type="reset" class="button1">OK</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#cancel').click(function(){
        alert('Hello');
    });

});
 </script>
```

I have added all the js files needed in the parent page.

There is no js error. The Alert doesn't get displayed

Comment: Any source or js error output?

Comment: Is the script (containing atm the alert) also supposed to be in the lightbox? If so, there's a chance that the lightbox kills it. Try moving even the alert script into the containing page.

Comment: If I move it to the containing page, it doesn't work. The basic functions work, but the other scripts do not work. Only if I add the script inside the lightbox page, it works. Is there a way to call the js files from the lightbox page, instead of writing it in the html page?

Answer (score 1):

Put your scripts in parent page or add that script in light box call back function.

Comment: Add the javascript and jquery coding also in the parent page? But there was no change, I did not get any of the function executed.

Comment: Please add your code here Or use jsFiddle. It will help me to understand your issue. are you getting any js error?